# ST7789 display: pins IM0, IM1, IM2, IM3 are not accesible

Tags: lcd, display, interface, rgb, peripheral-pin-select

In a [ST7789 LCD](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3787, how do I set the IM[3:0] pins for select the MPU Interface Mode? The manual just shows the values of IM[3:0] for each interface but doesn't explain how to program the IM pins.

Comment: This could do with a little more context and details. Perhaps include a pinout, link to the datasheet, details of the specific display module you are using etc.

Answer (score 1):

The device as a whole is not intended for it.

The device, as a whole, can be divided to 4 parts:

- The LCD glass with the pixels
- The LCD controller chip mounted on the glass
- Flat flex cable to interface the chip
- The PCB to interface the flat flex cable

The point is that even if the LCD controller chip has all the pins and interfaces, are all the interface pins and pins to set the interface even brought to the flat flex cable, or hardwired on the glass.

If the the flat flex contains all interfaces and pins to set them, there is no documentation about what the pinout is. If there was documenation about it, you would need to hack the existing PCB, or manufacture your own PCB.

You only have the PCB which comes with the device that may set the interface or not, but at least it provides you with the SPI interface.